# Awkward spacing in Multicols itemization?

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, multicol

In the following LaTeX itemize, I can't seem to get rid of the awkward space between "Object-Oriented" and "Programming". Does anyone know of some way to at least space the words out evenly?

Code:

```
\noindent \textbf{\underline{Selected Coursework}} \\
\vspace*{-2.0\multicolsep}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Object-Oriented Programming \& Data Structures
    \item Functional Programming
    \item Machine Learning
    \item Systems Programming
    \item Operating Systems
    \item Software Testing
    \item Database Systems
    \item Probability Models
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\vspace*{-0.6\multicolsep}
```

Result:

[image]

I just want a normal-sized space before "Programming".

Comment: use `\raggedright` and (unrelated) remove the spurious `\\ ` after `Selected Coursework` (which presumably generates a warning). It would be helpful if you supplied code in a form that shows the problem and allows answers to be tested, not just a fragment

Answer (score 2):

Justified text in narrow columns tends to require large inter-word space.

Use `\raggedright` or the slightly less ragged `\RaggedRight` (from the `ragged2e` package)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\addtolength\textwidth{4.5cm}% to approximate image shown
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{\underline{Selected Coursework}}


\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Object-Oriented Programming \& Data Structures
    \item Functional Programming
    \item Machine Learning
    \item Systems Programming
    \item Operating Systems
    \item Software Testing
    \item Database Systems
    \item Probability Models
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\hrule

\begin{multicols}{3}\raggedright
\begin{itemize}
    \item Object-Oriented Programming \& Data Structures
    \item Functional Programming
    \item Machine Learning
    \item Systems Programming
    \item Operating Systems
    \item Software Testing
    \item Database Systems
    \item Probability Models
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\hrule

\begin{multicols}{3}\RaggedRight
\begin{itemize}
    \item Object-Oriented Programming \& Data Structures
    \item Functional Programming
    \item Machine Learning
    \item Systems Programming
    \item Operating Systems
    \item Software Testing
    \item Database Systems
    \item Probability Models
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```